# Pair elements of lists without permutations

Tags: python, list

I have two identical lists `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (the same one can be used for this purpose).
I want to generate a third one which has this format:

```
[[1,2],
[2,3],
[3,5],
[4,1],
[5,4]]
```

The second column is basically a random shuffle of the second list, however I want to impose two constraints:

1. The list must not contain elements like `[1,1]`
2. The list must not contain, at the same time, elements `[x, y]` and `[y, x]`.

What I have so far is basically a loop that generates this 2D matrix, then checks line by line whether there is, anywhere else in the list, the reversed item (i.e. if the line is `[2,1]` it will check for `[1,2]`; this is taking care of both of my constraint as reversing `[1,1]` gives of course `[1,1]`):

```py
from random import shuffle

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
shuffList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # Note here I need a second list because I use shuffle()

while True:
    a=0
    shuffle(shuffList)
    newList = list(map(list, zip(myList, shuffList)))

    for i in newList:
        if list(reversed(i)) in newList:
            print(True)
            a=1
            break

    if a == 1:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

However, this seems very inefficient (and poorly written, I'm sure).
I was wondering whether there is a better way to do it.

Comment: does the order of the second col have to be random? Do you just need one of these output matrices or all possible ones?

Comment: This has to run several times, each time outputting a different, random one

Comment: The problem here is that depending on the preceding choices it's possible that you end up with a last element that you can't place because of the constraints you mentioned. This resembles features of the ['8 Queens'](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/8-queen-problem/) problem.

One question is whether it's a problem if your algorithm returns the same output twice just by chance? 
If so you could use an algorithm to solve 8 queens and precompute all possible configurations and then just return them one by one. At some point you will have exhausted all possible combinations.

Comment: Oh, yeah I am aware of that, thanks for pointing it out. It does not matter if the same output is repeated, sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Ok, so getting the same output on every call for a given input would also not be a problem?

Comment: That would probably be an issue. Think of a network configuration where nodes talk to each other. It doesn't matter in which order, but everyone has to talk with everyone else

Comment: I think if we want to allow, say, an option for any link to be disconnected at any time, it would probably be enough to open a new question

Comment: Note that your conditions are not sufficient to ensure all nodes talk to each other; for example consider the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`; a solution which meets your conditions is `[[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 1], [6, 2]]` however in this solution nodes 1,3 and 5 only talk to each other and nodes 2, 4 and 6 only talk to each other.

Comment: @Nick that's ok, in the next call they will have a different configuration, I only have those two constraints

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://ideone.com/yiTwIc) then? It won't give all possible combinations (but perhaps enough?) and it is very efficient. As long as `n != len(list)//2` the conditions are guaranteed to be met.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is not random, but I believe does meet the criterion of the OP:

1. The list must not contain elements like [1,1]
2. The list must not contain, at the same time, elements [x, y] and [y, x].

Assuming the values in each list are unique, and each list contains the same values (as the original example), we can reverse and slightly re-shuffle the second list, and do it a little differently depending on whether or not the length of the lists are odd or even:

```
import numpy as np

# Create the two lists
nums = list(range(0, 5))
nums2 = list(range(0, 5))

# reverse order `nums2`
nums2.reverse()


nums3 = []
if len(nums) % 2 == 0:
    # if the length of the list is even
    nums3_first = nums2.index(len(nums2)/2)
else:
    # if the length of the list is odd
    nums3_first = nums2.index((len(nums2)-1)/2)
    
nums3_second = nums2[0:np.int((len(nums2)-1)/2)]
nums3_last = nums2[np.int((len(nums2)-1)/2 + 1):]


# Construct the list of lists
nums3.append(nums3_first)
nums3 = nums3 + nums3_second + nums3_last
final = [list(x) for x in zip(nums, nums3)]
print(final)


# Test to ensure that the there are no reverse matches
# Result will return an empty list if the criteria is met
tester = [[x[1], x[0]] for x in final]
[x for x in final if x in tester]
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, however, this will yield the same result every time it's called?